# Identity server and client in one application- authorize by token does not work

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-core-mvc, openiddict

I'm creating web application including API and OAuth authorization code flow user authorization. So I have the `AccountController`

```
[HttpGet("/connect/auth")]
public IActionResult Authorize(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest();

    var application = _applicationRepository.Table
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == request.ClientId);

    if (application == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Application not recognized");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var parameters = request.GetParameters()
            .ToDictionary(parameter => parameter.Key, parameter => parameter.Value.ToString());

    return View(new AuthorizeModel
    {
        ApplicationName = application.DisplayName,
        Parameters = parameters,
        Scope = request.Scope
    });
}

[HttpPost("/connect/auth/accept")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AuthorizeAccept(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest();

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)));

    var application = _applicationRepository.Table
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == request.ClientId);

    if (application == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Application not recognized");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties(),
            OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    ticket.SetScopes(
        /* openid: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
        /* email: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
        /* profile: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile);
    ticket.SetResources("resource_server");

    return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

And my `Startup` class configuration

```
// services
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(setup =>
    {
        setup.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        setup.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        setup.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        setup.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        setup.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddMvcBinders()
    .EnableAuthorizationEndpoint("/connect/auth")
    .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
    .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
    .DisableHttpsRequirement()
    .UseJsonWebTokens()
    .AddEphemeralSigningKey();

services.AddMvc();

// app configuration
app.UseIdentity();

app.UseOAuthValidation();

app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<OpenIddictOptions>>().Value.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
app.UseOpenIddict();

// Used to make OpenId connect request available for auth accept route
public class AuthorizationProvider : OpenIddictProvider<OpenIddictApplication, OpenIddictAuthorization, OpenIddictScope, OpenIddictToken>
{
    public override Task MatchEndpoint(MatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.Options.AuthorizationEndpointPath.HasValue && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(context.Options.AuthorizationEndpointPath))
            context.MatchAuthorizationEndpoint();

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

So I can login and obtain access token, but when I'm using the token for API calls to controllers with `[Authorize]` attribute, it does not recognize me as authorized user. I also noticed that `ApplicationId` and `AuthorizationId` values of records in `OpenIddictTokens` table are null.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JWT access tokens with the validation middleware (`app.UseOAuthValidation())` as it only works with the default format.

Either remove `.UseJsonWebTokens()` to use the default access token format or use the JWT bearer middleware (`app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(...)`) and it should work.